# Excel VBA program crashing when selecting from listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am really puzzled with some error causing crash and I don't know what it is. Can someone identify the problem?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3l3q985y75n9nup/xxx.xlsb?dl=0

In form "SettingsForm" line containing `Me.CheckBoxXlGrouped2.Value = .XlGrouped2` causes crash.
In excel Ctrl+r, tab "SQL Tables and Columns" when you select something from the left listbox (listbox3) it will crash excel.
However if you comment out `Me.CheckBoxXlGrouped2.Value = .XlGrouped2` the program won't crash.

Comment: Please - enough info in the question itself to identify and reproduce the problem. Most, if not all, are hesitant to download and open an Excel file.

Comment: It's impossible because I don't know what the problem is and what is causing it. So it can't be just a segment of a code.

Comment: It's best to describe your problem in the body of the question, and include the relevant code there also.  Most people here will not download and open a macro-enabled file (unless they've specifically asked you to share a copy)

Comment: The program is clean and trustworthy. You can open it in sandbox system if there are worries. Or just open it with macros disabled and try to identify if I did something wrong.

Comment: @DamGal - nothing personal!  Most folk here likely do not have ready access to a sandbox system, and a lot of files offered for download here contain a lot of unrelated code, which all needs to be reviewed before allowing anything to run.  It's all a bit of a pain unless you're already invested in trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it appears whenever I added new checkbox after deleting the old one it inherited some bugged stuff from previous one that was causing crashes. So I kept the old one, added new one then deleted the old one. Now it works again. Weird.